# Differences between PHPExcel and PHPExcelReader

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I'm on a project in my work where I have intended to read data from an .xls file. 
I have seen the existence of some libraries, but it has generated some doubts.

For example: PHPExcel and PHPExcelReader, are they the same?

I have not found much documentation related to PHPExcelReader, that led me to doubt what is the use that is given to the library.

The project I am about to make consists of a form you have to complete a field, from which complete data in the field, find if there is any column in the .xls file with that information.

This is possible with PHPExcel or PHPExcelReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they aren't the same:

[PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/) is a library maintained on github that can read and write a variety of spreadsheet formats. Documentation can be found [online](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki) or in the [/Documentation folder](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Documentation) of the library.

PHP Excel Reader could be any of 3 different libraries

- [PHP-ExcelReader](http://phpexcelreader.sourceforge.net/)
- [PHP_Excel_Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)
- [PHP_Excel_Reader2](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader2/)

none of them any longer supported, that could read BIFF-format (`xls`) files. You can find any available documentation at the linked sites.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! From the brief description made ​​about the project, which tool do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend the one that I wrote: PHPExcel